# date format error-type mismatch

Tags: vba

below is the code in which I am getting error at 
If DOJ = " " Then. The error is "error 13, type mismatch"

I want to check if the cell is empty or not, if empty then change inner color to blue, but it is giving error as type mismatch.
Kindly help to resolve.

```
Sub BGVslaCheck()
fpath = Worksheets("Refrence").Range("C9").Value
fname = Worksheets("Refrence").Range("b9").Value & ".xlsx"
Dim Emp1 As Date
Dim DOJ As Date
Dim Cri As Date
Dim Edu As Date

'On Error Resume Next

Workbooks.Open (fpath & fname)
Worksheets("BGV").Select
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
i = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

For J = 11 To i

        DOJ = Worksheets("BGV").Range("c" & J).Value
        Cri = Worksheets("BGV").Range("g" & J).Value
        Edu = Worksheets("BGV").Range("i" & J).Value
        Emp1 = Worksheets("BGV").Range("K" & J).Value



        a = wf.NetworkDays(DOJ, Cri)
        b = wf.NetworkDays(DOJ, Edu)
        c = wf.NetworkDays(DOJ, Emp)
            Worksheets("BGV").Range("N" & J).Select
                If a > 14 Or b > 14 Or c > 14 Then
                    With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = VBA.RGB(250, 0, 0)
                    End With
                Else
                    With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = VBA.RGB(0, 250, 0)
                    End With
                End If

                'If DOJ = " " Or Cri = " " Or Edu = " " Then
                If DOJ = " " Then
                    With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = VBA.RGB(0, 0, 250)
                    End With
                End If
Next

Workbooks(fname).Close
```

Comment: Additionally, is `VBA.RGB` valid syntax? Couldn't you just say `.Color = RGB(0, 0, 250)`, etc.?

Comment: @dwirony, yes its valid and tried your suggestion, that is also working.thanks. Lowpar- thanks for your answer. the code is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOJ is dimmed as a date, while your check is for a string. The below should work alternatively, you could keep it as a date and do if isempty(DOJ) then.

```
Sub BGVslaCheck()
fpath = Worksheets("Refrence").Range("C9").Value
fname = Worksheets("Refrence").Range("b9").Value & ".xlsx"
Dim Emp1 As Date
Dim DOJ
Dim Cri As Date
Dim Edu As Date

'On Error Resume Next

Workbooks.Open (fpath & fname)
Worksheets("BGV").Select
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
i = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

For J = 11 To i

        DOJ = Worksheets("BGV").Range("c" & J).Value
        Cri = Worksheets("BGV").Range("g" & J).Value
        Edu = Worksheets("BGV").Range("i" & J).Value
        Emp1 = Worksheets("BGV").Range("K" & J).Value



        a = wf.NetworkDays(DOJ, Cri)
        b = wf.NetworkDays(DOJ, Edu)
        c = wf.NetworkDays(DOJ, Emp)
            Worksheets("BGV").Range("N" & J).Select
                If a > 14 Or b > 14 Or c > 14 Then
                    With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = VBA.RGB(250, 0, 0)
                    End With
                Else
                    With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = VBA.RGB(0, 250, 0)
                    End With
                End If
  'you could try: if isempty(DOJ) then 
                'If DOJ = " " Or Cri = " " Or Edu = " " Then
                If DOJ = " " Then
                    With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = VBA.RGB(0, 0, 250)
                    End With
                End If
Next

Workbooks(fname).Close
```